# Spring mvc jsp error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have spring mvc application and I am getting a weird error when I try to access a page. Since I am no expert on jsp etc I have troubles finding the error.

The exception is this one:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.setHtmlEscape(Ljava/lang/String;)V
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.login_jspx._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(login_jspx.java:123)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.login_jspx._jspService(login_jspx.java:96)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
>           at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
>           at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
>           at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
>           at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
>           at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
>           at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
>           at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
>           at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
>           at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
>           at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
>           at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(default_jspx.java:234)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspService(default_jspx.java:96)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>           at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
>           at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
>           at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
>           at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)

My web.xml in case it helps is this one:

> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
>       version="3.0">

```
<display-name>mock-app-admin</display-name>

<description>mock-app-admin</description>


<!-- Enable escaping of form submission contents -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mock-app-admin-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!-- Handles Spring requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mock-app-admin-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mock-app-admin-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/uncaughtException</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/resourceNotFound</location>
</error-page>
```

My dependencies are as follows:

> ```
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
>         <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
>         <version>4.2.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
>         <version>${jackson.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
>         <version>1.9.13</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

```
    <!-- Infinispan -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${infinispan.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-client-hotrod</artifactId>
        <version>${infinispan.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Camel -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>

    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-mail</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-velocity</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-csv</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache CXF Version -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf.flash</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>gr.flash.air.platform.aspects</groupId>
        <artifactId>flash-air-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${flash-air-aspects.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-tools-common</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache POI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Social -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-facebook.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-facebook.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-twitter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-linkedin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-linkedin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-c3p0.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax-persistence.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgres.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
        <version>${mysql.version}</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-solr.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax-servlet.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-fileupload.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl-api.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl-impl.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>${el-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda-time.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles-jsp.version}</version>

    </dependency>


    <!-- General -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.vidageek</groupId>
        <artifactId>mirror</artifactId>
        <version>${mirror.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${validation.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <!-- Aspectj -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito-all.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jbehave-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

with the following spring versions:

```
<java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.6.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <spring-data-solr.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring-data-solr.version>
    <spring-social.version>1.1.0.RELEASE</spring-social.version>
    <spring-social-facebook.version>1.1.1.RELEASE</spring-social-facebook.version>
    <spring-social-twitter.version>1.1.0.RELEASE</spring-social-twitter.version>
    <spring-social-linkedin.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring-social-linkedin.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.2</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.0.7</logback.version>
    <mirror.version>1.5.1</mirror.version>
    <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
    <validation.version>1.0.0.GA</validation.version>
    <jta.version>1.1</jta.version>
    <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.1</aspectj.version>
    <javax-servlet.version>3.0.1</javax-servlet.version>
    <javax-persistence.version>1.0.2</javax-persistence.version>
    <mockito-all.version>1.9.0</mockito-all.version>
    <jackson.version>2.4.1</jackson.version>
    <guava.version>13.0.1</guava.version>
    <tiles-jsp.version>2.2.2</tiles-jsp.version>
    <commons-codec.version>1.5</commons-codec.version>
    <jsp-api.version>2.1</jsp-api.version>
    <guava.version>13.0.1</guava.version>
    <joda-time.version>1.6</joda-time.version>
    <el-api.version>1.0</el-api.version>
    <jstl-impl.version>1.2</jstl-impl.version>
    <jstl-api.version>1.2</jstl-api.version>
    <commons-fileupload.version>1.2.2</commons-fileupload.version>
    <build-helper-maven-plugin.version>1.7</build-helper-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <aspectj-maven-plugin.version>1.4</aspectj-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-eclipse-plugin.version>2.7</maven-eclipse-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>2.5</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <wtpversion.version>2.0</wtpversion.version>
    <pipes.version>1.5</pipes.version>
    <neo4j-cypher-dsl.version>1.6</neo4j-cypher-dsl.version>
    <camel.version>2.10.4</camel.version>
    <gdata.version>1.47.1</gdata.version>
    <httpclient.version>4.2.3</httpclient.version>
    <hibernate-core.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate-core.version>
    <hibernate-entitymanager.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate-entitymanager.version>
    <hibernate-c3p0.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate-c3p0.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.23</mysql.version>
    <postgres.version>9.1-901.jdbc4</postgres.version>
    <jaxb2-maven-plugin.version>1.5</jaxb2-maven-plugin.version>
    <cxf.version>2.7.8</cxf.version>
    <infinispan.version>5.2.1.Final</infinispan.version>
    <commons-dbcp.version>1.0</commons-dbcp.version>
    <jbehave-maven-plugin.version>3.7.5</jbehave-maven-plugin.version>
    <cxf.flash.version>2.8.0</cxf.flash.version>
    <poi.version>3.9</poi.version>
    <tomcat7-maven-plugin.version>2.0</tomcat7-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.13</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <flash-air-aspects.version>1.0.0-FINAL</flash-air-aspects.version>
    <velocitytools.version>2.0</velocitytools.version>
```

This is the login.jspx:

```html
<div xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <spring:message code="security_login_title" var="title" htmlEscape="false" />
  <util:panel id="title" title="${title}">
    <c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
      <div class="errors">
        <p>
          <spring:message code="security_login_unsuccessful" />
          <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
          .
        </p>
      </div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${empty param.login_error}">
      <p>
        <spring:message code="security_login_message" />
      </p>
    </c:if>
    <spring:url value="/resources/j_spring_security_check" var="form_url" />
    <form name="f" action="${fn:escapeXml(form_url)}" method="POST">
      <div>
        <label for="j_username">
          <spring:message code="security_login_form_name" />
        </label>
        <input id="j_username" type='text' name='j_username' style="width:150px" />
        <spring:message code="security_login_form_name_message" var="name_msg" htmlEscape="false" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
          <c:set var="sec_name_msg">
            <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${name_msg}</spring:escapeBody>
          </c:set>
          Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : "j_username", widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox", widgetAttrs : {promptMessage: "${sec_name_msg}", required : true}})); 
        </script>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        <label for="j_password">
          <spring:message code="security_login_form_password" />
        </label>
        <input id="j_password" type='password' name='j_password' style="width:150px" />
        <spring:message code="security_login_form_password_message" var="pwd_msg" htmlEscape="false" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
          <c:set var="sec_pwd_msg">
            <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${pwd_msg}</spring:escapeBody>
          </c:set>
          Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : "j_password", widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox", widgetAttrs : {promptMessage: "${sec_pwd_msg}", required : true}})); 
        </script>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="submit">
        <script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({elementId:'proceed', event:'onclick'}));</script>
        <spring:message code="button_submit" var="submit_label" htmlEscape="false" />
        <input id="proceed" type="submit" value="${fn:escapeXml(submit_label)}" />
        <spring:message code="button_reset" var="reset_label" htmlEscape="false" />
        <input id="reset" type="reset" value="${fn:escapeXml(reset_label)}" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </util:panel>
</div>
```

and footer is (included in layout):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
 xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
 xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
 xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
 xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" id="footer" version="2.0">
 <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
 <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

 <spring:url value="/" var="home" />
 <span> <a href="${home}"> <spring:message code="button_home" />
 </a>
 </span>
 <c:if test="${pageContext['request'].userPrincipal != null}">
  <c:out value=" | " />
  <span> <spring:url value="/resources/j_spring_security_logout"
    var="logout" /> <a href="${logout}"> <spring:message
     code="security_logout" />
  </a>
  </span>
 </c:if>

 <span id="language"> <c:out value=" | " /> <spring:message
   code="global_language" /> <c:out value=": " /> <util:language
   label="English" locale="en" /> <util:language label="Greek"
   locale="el" />
 </span>
 <util:theme />

 <spring:url value="/resources/images/springsource-logo.png" var="logo" />
 <spring:message code="global_sponsored" htmlEscape="false"
  var="sponsored" />
 <span> <a href="http://springsource.com"
  title="${fn:escapeXml(sponsored)}"> <img align="right"
   alt="${fn:escapeXml(sponsored)}" src="${logo}" />
 </a>
 </span>
</div>
```

Every idea would be appreciated.

Comment: You are using a incorrect version of spring mvc jar.

Comment: i am using spring-webmvc-4.1.0.RELEASE and spring-webmvc-4.1.0.RELEASE. what is the problem with this?

Comment: `MessageTag.setHtmlEscape(Ljava/lang/String;)` means `setHtmlEscape(String arg)`.   spring-webmvc-4.x doesn't have that method, earlier versions of spring-mvc had that method and the method signature was changed to `setHtmlEscape(boolean arg)` in v4.x. Which means, you do have a transitive dependency to an older version of spring-mvc.

Comment: @Mubin the think is that I dont see anywhere to use setHtmlEscape(Ljava/lang/String;) I alsqay use with boolean, such as <spring:message code="application_name" var="app_name" htmlEscape="false"/>

Comment: can you list out all the version properties, just like you did it for spring libraries?

Comment: @Mubin ok I have add all the versions. thank you very much

Comment: You should show `login.jspx` and say what are lines 123 and 96

Comment: @SergeBallesta i added login but it does not have lines 96 and 123. i added footer as well which is included in layout

Comment: Sorry - lines 96 and 123 refer to the java version generated by the container. If you can find `login_jspx.java` under container files (it exists for Tomcat), you could try to see what lines in JSP  correspond to those lines in the java file, even if it is rather hard to read at first contact ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta 96 line is this one :

  if (_jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(_jspx_page_context))
        return;

and 123 is this one: 

 _jspx_th_spring_005fmessage_005f0.setHtmlEscape("false");

i have no idea what is going on...

Comment: it seems that this is the problem:
.setHtmlEscape("false");

in the generated files, but I do not understand why. this is the way I am using htmlEscape in the code:

htmlEscape="false"

Comment: Check if the lib folder of server (tomcat?) where the application is deployed contains any spring jars. The issue is purely because of conflicting jars. The container is using Spring version less than 4 for compiling your JSPs.

Comment: @Mubin if you mean ts $tomcathome/lib no it does not contain any spring jars. the lib folder of the deployed application does contain spring jars as it should, but in the version spring-web-4.1.0.RELEASE. so it should i think

Comment: are there any other applications deployed in the same tomcat container? If so remove them out for now and deploy only this application.

Comment: @Mubin no there arent :(

Comment: @giannisapi Can't think of anything else that can cause this problem.

Comment: @Mubin thanks for your help anyway... I ll try to figure out the problem and update here

Comment: @Mubin the work folder of tomcat had more applications inside. removed them and now it works fine.. what can I say, the clear mind of monday morning... thank you

Comment: nice to hear that you were able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end the sollution was pretty simple. In the work directory of the tomcat server, there were other apps that conflicted with this specific application I was trying to deploy.

Comment: Cleaning my tomcat deployment directory did the trick as well.